# How to make clickable URL's in JSON response from REST using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, rest

I have an `AngularJS`, `JS`, `JQ`, `HTML5` web app, which can send different http methods to project's `RESTful Web Service` and receive responses from it. Response comes in JSON and looks like this:

[image]

This is displayed in a `<pre>` element this way:

```
<div ng-controller="responseController">
    <span class="status-{{response.status}}">{{response.code}} {{response.description}}</span>
    <pre>{{response.data}}</pre>
    <p id="responseHeaders">Response headers:</p>
    <table>
        <tr  ng-repeat="header in response.headers">
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="addToHeaders(header)">{{header.name}}</a></td>
            <td><span>{{header.value}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I want is to have all the URL's that are received in JSON clickable, so I could hang a `ng-click` on them and go on with next steps. But I can't do it in a `<pre>` element.

Any ideas how this can be solved? Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a directive ([here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fwca9h4yNZhJ8FGR8BK5?p=preview)):

```
.directive('jsonLink', function() {
    var hrefLinks=function (obj, pretty) {
      var space = pretty || '';
      var html = '';
      $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if ($.isPlainObject(val)) {
          html += key + ': <br>';
          html += hrefLinks(val, space + '&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        } else if (key === 'href') {
          html += space + 'LINK: <a href="' + val + '">' + val + '</a><br>';
        } else {
          html += space + key + ': ' + val + '<br>';
        }
      });
      return html;
    }
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        obj: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.html(hrefLinks(scope.obj));
      }
    };
  })
```

Then drop this in your HTML

```
<json-link obj="objWithLinks"></json-link>
```

Comment: That's close BUT I need to display all of the properties, not only href. By the way it doesn't work for some reasons..no error is thrown.

Comment: The plnkr is broken or it's broken when you copy it across to your own code?  I've also updated hrefLinks to print out everything.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to replace all URLs within the response body with links.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links#21925491) answer.
You have some libraries there that will solve your problem.

[Autolinker.js](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js) seems like a good choice.

Comment: This is ok If the text is static. But in my case it is generating dynamically. And this huge string of text can contain unlimited amount of http addresses. How am I supposed to find every href inside of it to call this function?

Comment: The library does this(the search) for you. Unlimited links?! You should not have any performance issues unless you have a few thousands links in your response.