# Angular displaying the <a> as HYPERLINK from the response as string in HTML

Tags: angular, hyperlink

I have an api which gives me a string and I have to show the response on my HTML file, but after a lot of research I'm unable to figure out what to do.

The problem is that in the response the string has some `<a>XYZ</a>` tag in it and **I need to show XYZ as the hyperlink**. Right now the data is coming like

[image: RESPONSE ON THE WEB PAGE]

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

As you can see the response, the full Google is coming on the page without the hyperlink simply the text from the response where I want to display the Google only and also with the hyperlink.

**EDITS**

**HTML**

```
<p *ngIf="value && string">
  {{string.getString(value)}}
</p>
```

And I have tried doing with the this also

```
<p *ngIf="value && string">
  [innerHtml]="string.getString(value)"
</p>
```

It printed the same text in the webpage and moreover it didn't get any data

String is a service which I'm using to and getString() is method in it.

**String Service**

```
export class StringService {

 string : any

 constructor(private http : HttpClient) {
    this.http.get("/strings").subscribe(data => {
       this.strings = data['strings']
    })
 }

 getString(key : string){
   if(key == "WEB_ABOUT_US")
      return this.strings.WEB_ABOUT_US;
   else if(key == "WEB_CLASSES_TITLE")
      return this.strings.WEB_CLASSES_TITLE;

   return null  
 }

}
```

The response from the api :

```
{
   "strings": {
      "WEB_ABOUT_US": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href=\"www.google.co.in\">Google</a> Sed tellus justo, euismod non sodales eget, faucibus accumsan odio. Nunc quis venenatis dui. Vestibulum ut nunc nec augue imperdiet lobortis vitae eget ex. Curabitur ut elit et lacus euismod fringilla. Vivamus interdum massa quis sollicitudin ornare. Sed sed urna id diam sollicitudin tempus vel in elit. Duis malesuada massa et purus imperdiet, ac varius nulla volutpat. In feugiat quis sapien et tempus."
    }
}
```

What I have done so far is I went to this : [How to make clickable URL's in JSON response from REST using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058696/how-to-make-clickable-urls-in-json-response-from-rest-using-angularjs)

Read about [Autolinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js) but it is not the thing which I'm looking for. Kindly help to achieve this in angular form. If any question comes up I'm here to explain. Thanks

**SOLVED**

Thanks to all of you who gave their time and then helped me out but special thanks to @PierreDuc [PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/pierreduc) for the help which did the magic. So the thing which I had to do I was not working on it correctly.

```
<p [innerHTML]="string.getString('WEB_ABOUT_US')"></p>
```

and it worked. Thanks Again!!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show us _how_ you are inserting this content into your document first of all.

Comment: You're probably using string interpolation `{{value}}`, and you should use `[innerHTML]` binding like  `[innerHtml]="value"`

Comment: are you setting the text to that? you need to set the innerHTML to the `<a ...></a>`

Comment: Are you using angularjs or angular 2+?

Comment: @CBroe The reason why I asked like this is because I'm getting the response all I need to do is to get the response in that format. That's it. But I'll do it as asked.

Comment: @Markai yes. Angular 4

Comment: @PierreDuc I have tried using this in my code like this `[innerHtml]="value"` but it printed the same thing on my page nothing like I wanted  : [innerHtml]="string.getString(value)" like this on my page, now no data is coming up

Comment: @PierreDuc both will display the returned data as text, the innerHTML needs to be set for it to work as expected

Comment: @CBroe I have added the code, in the edit section

Comment: well youre telling the app to use the string form of whatever you're being sent

Comment: Can you just add the response that you got from api call

Comment: @mast3rd3mon isn't that the same as I said, or is there a difference between `innerHtml` and `innerHTML` that I don't know about :)?

Comment: @PierreDuc 1st, you edited that comment after i posted mine. 2nd, you have to do it from the code, you cant in the html

Comment: @mast3rd3mon pretty sure you misread though, because I didn't edit anything, which reflects in the OP's response to my comment, and how can you not bind a property which contains html inside the template?

Comment: @PierreDuc you did edit, i can see the edit marker. the innerHTML is set from getting the element within js/ts code

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes, I changed 'You probably' to 'You're probably' 20 
seconds after I posted it. I figured proper English would be better, but if that changed how you perceived and interpreted the comment, then I'm sorry. Looks like you were so confused by that change, it took you 7 minutes to write the comment :)

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I have done this in my ts file like `[innerHTML]=this.string.getString(this.value)` but I got this error `Cannot find name '
innerHTML'.` Pardon me for that, but could you please show it in the form of code, so that I could also learn something new?

Comment: you have to get the element reference, and set the innerHTML of the element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerHTML is not working for some tags like button or custom tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879407/innerhtml-is-not-working-for-some-tags-like-button-or-custom-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it- By default Angular is sanitizing potential unsafe content

```
 import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 html: any;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.html = domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<b>Test</b> <a href="google.com" >My Test</a>');
  }
```

StackBlitz example-

See also https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cijzw

Comment: So, it was a quiet correct somehow, but when I pass the value in the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml(string.getString("WEB_ABOUT_US"))`, it is not actually working on it at all probably it should work. Throwing a lot of errors. It only works when you just provide it like `bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<b>Test</b> <a href="google.com" >My Test</a>')`

Comment: Look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cijzw, Here I have dummy data. It's working fine.